# Calculation of an impulse response of h[n]

Tags: z-transform, transfer-function

I am currently looking at the z-transform and am using a great youtube reference to help me, however I am struggling on some basic step. How do I get the impulse response array of h[n] = [ ... ] shown in the lecture at the following URL - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEJp46SFgV4&ab_channel=DavidDorran

[image]

I can do the following which I believe to be correct but do not know how to get the array out as shown in purple.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That purple array is giving the impulse response over time. You can get it directly from the difference equation. Assume initial rest, $y[-1]=0$, then write out the impulse response for $n=0, 1, 2, ...$. If you do that you will get:

\begin{align}
 h[0]&=1+0 \\
 h[1] &= 0 + 0.5 \\
 h[2] &= 0 + 0.25 \\
 h[3] &= 0 + 0.125 \\
 ...
\end{align}